# Inverse proportions, but the other way around

Tags: phrase-requests, mathematics

The title sucks, I know... Anyway:

As part of a game I'm making, one of the buildings decreases the time it takes to build other things. Like so:

At level 0: Full time
At level 1: Full time / 2
At level 2: Full time / 3
At level 3: Full time / 4
...

So basically, the construction time is inversely proportional to this buildling's level. But so far my sentence to describe this effect is:

> This building reduces construction times by a factor proportional to its level.

Is this correct? Is there a better way to phrase this? By my understanding this means that the factor (the denominator of the fraction) is proportional to the level, is this correct? Does "level + 1" count as proportional?

Comment: 'Construction time of new buildings is inverse proportional to  the number of levels of the main building'.

Comment: It would be a good idea to clarify the question.  From the problem description, I don't understand the construction time equation or what is being constructed or who is contructing what.  Is Mitch's statement correct? (with inverse replaced by inversely)

Comment: I see someone voted to close as Too Localised. I've voted to close as General Reference. What's the opposite of *inversely proportional?*  **Proportional**!

Comment: So why can't you just say "inversely proportional"?  It seems to me like the right expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be better to talk about construction *speed* rather than construction *time*.  You can say: "At level *k*, widget construction speed is *k+1* times as fast as at level 0."  Alternately, provide a little table of construction speed, with entries like "Level 2: 30 units per day".

Comment: Derivatives come in handy here and there.